# Calling functions one from the other and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have two timers with two boolean variables and two functions. The first timer is triggered by a click that put true one of the booleans; once the timer reach some conditions this timer is off setting false the boolean and another timer is triggered setting true the second boolean and calling the second timer.

Same once the second timer reach some conditions, the timer is off setting the second boolean false and I try to trigger the first timer setting the first boolean true and calling the first timer, but it dosn't work.

**I cannot call the function that is declared underneath the funcion where I do the call.**

My code in JavaScript is:

```
var active=false;
var activeBreak=false;
...
function breakDown(){
     if(activeBreak){
         ...
         if(some conditions){
                 active=true;
                 activeBreak=false;
                 countDown();// **This call doesn't work.Black in                                                jsbin**
             }
         }

  }

function countDown(){
           if(active){
               ...
               if(someConditions){
                    active=false;
                    activeBreak=true;
                    breakDown();// *This call works. Blue in jsbin*
                 }
             }
 }
...

$("#circle").click(function(){
           active=true;
           countDown(); // *This call works*/
     });
```

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Maybe 'someConditions' never occur ? .. is there any use of a js timeout function?

Comment: Yes the conditions occur. I am using jsbin.com and the call to breakDown() from function countDown is blue (active), but the call to countDown() from function breakDown is black(no active) and that is what happens.

Comment: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/padizuloxe/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/* Global variables */
var state = 'STOPPED';
var timeSession = 1;
var timeBreak = 1;

var timeout = 0;

function resetTimer(time) {
  timeout = (new Date()).getTime() + (time*60*1000);
}

function changeState() {

  if (state === 'SESSION') {
    state = 'BREAK';
    resetTimer(timeBreak);
  } else if (state === 'BREAK' || state === 'STOPPED') {
    state = 'SESSION';
    resetTimer(timeSession);
  }
  $('#text').text(state);
}

/* Function for the countdown ****************************/
function countDown (){

  if (state !== 'STOPPED') {
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();

    if (timeout <= time) {
      changeState();
      return;
    }

    var s = Math.floor((timeout - time) / 1000);
    var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s = s - m*60;

    $('#timer').text(""+((timeout - time) / 1000)+" "+timeout+" "+m+":"+("0"+s).substr(-2));

  }
  setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}

/*****Click Break ********************/
$("#breakMinus").click(function(){
  if (timeBreak > 1) {
    --timeBreak;
  }
  $("#breakContent").html(timeBreak);
});

$("#breakPlus").click(function(){
  ++timeBreak;
  $("#breakContent").html(timeBreak);
});

/******Click Session Length****************/ 
$("#seMinus").click(function(){
  if (timeSession > 1) {
    --timeSession;
  }
  $("#seContent").html(timeSession);
});

$("#sePlus").click(function(){
  ++timeSession;
  $("#seContent").html(timeSession);
});    

/***********Click circle****************/
$("#circle").click(changeState);


setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
$('#text').text(state);

});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is behavior that you want?

Comment: There are two clocks in the same place<div>clock</div>: SESSION and BREAK. The clock SESSION is firstly triggered with a click in the div that calls function countDown.Once countDown reach 00:00 the clock SESSION is off and it starts clock BREAK disabling function countDown and starting function breakDown. When breakDown reach 00:00 same the oposite: again clock SESSION should be on disabling function breakDown and calling countDown. This last doesn't happen: the call to countDown is not active in function breakDown.

Comment: And while the clock is running, what does changing the break or session length do?  Does these change take effect only at the end of a clock reaching 0?

Comment: Only it takes effect at the end of a clock: SESSION(00:59,00:58,00:57,...) when it reaches 00.00 the div shows BREAK (00:59,00:58,00:57,...) when it reaches 00.00 the div should show SESSION (00:59,00:58,00:57,...)